# How to test the release build on device with Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, provisioning

I've just finished writing an update for my app, and now I want to submit it to the app store.

I've thoroughly tested it in debug mode on multiple devices, but I want to test it with the release build just to make sure nothing screws up.

In Xcode 4.0.2, when I wanted to **test** the release build (i.e. not distribute), I would just do the following

1. In the project settings, make sure that the release code signing is set to "iPhone Developer" not "iPhone Distribution"
2. Go to `Edit scheme...`, and change the **Run** scheme to **Release** instead of **Debug**.
3. Make sure my distribution provisioning profile is installed in Xcode
4. Run it on the device, make sure everything works.

If it all works, I would then distribute with the following:

1. Change the code signing to "iPhone Distribution"
2. Make sure the **Archive** scheme is set to **Release**
3. Archive
4. Submit

Now the problem is, with Xcode 4.2, I can't test the release build on my device. - When I build it with release to my iPod, I get an alert:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

So, I checked my provisioning profiles under the main "Library" section of the Devices pane (all provisioning profiles), and I found my distribution profile there.

The problem is, the provisioning profile says **"This profile cannot be installed on deivces"**.

So, if I can't use the distribution profile with a device - how am I supposed to test the release build?

I would appreciate any advice with this issue - sorry if there's something obvious I'm missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933

> How do I confirm my Provisioning Profile is for App Store distribution?
>
> You can confirm whether your provisioning profile is an App Store Distribution profile within the Xcode Organizer > Devices tab > Provisioning Profiles section under "Library"; single-click to select the particular provisioning profile and in the Header Pane, the "Devices" text will read "This profile cannot be installed on devices" if it is an App Store Provisioning Profile.

That means you would need to create another distribution profile for testing.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933. And for testing, you should create an ad-hoc distribution profile and use that on test-devices. To see how to create an ad-hoc distribution profile, look for "How-To" section in the iOS provisioning portal -> Provisioning -> How-To